# Error in processing request Error Code: 200 - through cPanel, myphpadmin. After been hacked

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, cpanel

I'm using cPanel with myphpadmin SQL Database and Wordpress, and I got hacked!

I have managed to restore the wordpress website from a backup. I have restored the database along with all the files. I did through the restore in cPanel.

I wanted to check the SQL DB and make sure the user name of the hacker was gone. As it showed up in the WP users. Wordfence alerted me that a user was created outside of WP.

When I try to access the 'myphpadmin' in different browsers (it makes no difference) I get this error...

> "Error in processing request Error Code: 200 Error text: OK (rejected)
> It seems that the connection to server has been lost. Please check
> your network connectivity and server status."

[image]

I have tried contacting my server, they seem hopeless. They keep telling me to reach out to Sucuri. But I can't afford their service. Besides, with some direction, Im sure I can manage it. I just need to get past this error.

After I click on the DB that is located to the left of this message in left pane. I get like unformatted page. its so strange.

I've looked up online, there are solutions using WAMP but not through cPanel.

I added an image of what it looks like after I click the DB name.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you check that ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtsW0dzTCoU

Comment: You also can check that link : https://bobcares.com/blog/phpmyadmin-error-code-200/. The idea is to increase the memory_limit, you still need some research to adapt it for cpanel i think. Sorry i don't know much, but i get the it's a hard time for you now so i try :)

Comment: If you only have an account in cpanel shared server you can install a phpmyadmin inside any public folder and try again to reach your database setting its config files.  If the problem is inside cpanel->phpmyadmin access then your hosting company should fix it, not you. If you owns the server you can open a ticket to cpanel staff via WHM asking them to fix phpmyadmin installed by cpanel. Btw, sorry, this question is off-topic. Not code related really or showed. Wish you luck!